70's to 90's thriller movie - by the end, the villain chases a woman and is shot in the head by a police officer
The movie is in English, possibly made in the US.
Story points that I remember:

By the near end of the film, the villain (I think a young adult) attacks a woman in her room.  The woman was wearing briefs, shorts or may have just been topless.
The villain chases her outside onto a street, and he is apprehended by the authorities. The woman is comforted by a trench-coat wearing officer/detective (I think he had a bushy mustache and wore glasses)
The villain then crazily boasts that he will eventually be back from jail and be back to finish the job. The officer/detective tells him that he won't, and proceeds to fatally shoot the villain in the head.


10 to Midnight, (1983), with Charles Bronson as the bushy-mustache detective.  It was actually a naked serial killer, but according to the "Goofs" section on IMDB:

When Warren is chasing Betty through the woods, he's wearing pants
  while running in some shots.

